# UIActivityController is not working for message and social platforms

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, ios17

```
let shareMesage = "\(StringUtils.getTranslationWithKey("checknow")) \(package_name)\n\n\(urlString)"
let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [shareMesage], applicationActivities: nil)
activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.custom_navigationBar
activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [ UIActivity.ActivityType.airDrop, UIActivity.ActivityType.postToFacebook ]
self.present(activityViewController, animated: true)
```

Following errors getting for iOS 17 when clicking on any platforms

```
Attempt to present <SLComposeViewController: 0x12283ba00> on <UINavigationController: 0x122816000> (from <SHSheetSceneViewController: 0x11f258f00>) whose view is not in the window hierarchy.
Trying to perform <UISocialActivity: 0x282e18b00> activityType:net.whatsapp.WhatsApp.ShareExtension activityTitle:UISocialActivity but there is already an activity performing:<SHSheetActivityPerformer: 0x2839638e0>
```

Presented the activity controller, clicked on what's app & message but activity controller is not dismissed and showing the error

```
Attempt to present <SLComposeViewController: 0x12283ba00> on <UINavigationController: 0x122816000> (from <SHSheetSceneViewController: 0x11f258f00>) whose view is not in the window hierarchy.
Trying to perform <UISocialActivity: 0x282e18b00> activityType:net.whatsapp.WhatsApp.ShareExtension activityTitle:UISocialActivity but there is already an activity performing:<SHSheetActivityPerformer: 0x2839638e0>
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76980934/uiactivityviewcontroller-no-longer-displaying-application-activity-icons-under-i

Comment: @Chandaboy, that’s related to image. But my issue is different, I am neither able to navigate nor activity is dismissing.